# Matching image position before comparing image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My goal is to make image 1 and image 2 in the same position before comparing and get the difference between images using python. Take this example:

[image]

as you can see image 1 and image 2 is the same image, but image 2 is shifted and have another hole that image one didn't have. I want to compare this two images but first, I need to make image 1 and image 2 in the same position.

How would I go about finding the difference in the image?

Edit :

Real Image

[image]

Comment: A hand-made diagram is never enough to give good advice. Can you show real images ?

Comment: thank you for your reply @YvesDaoust I added the real images.

Comment: it is always holes? I think it is better to first threshold the image so that only holes are visible and the rest is white. Try segmenting per row? I mean the part that you can shift individually, try shifting it until you get the "best match", probably it will not be perfectly equal but similar. then find the object that gives less than certain percentage of matching.... this is just a rough idea for you to get  it starting :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be divided into two parts:
1) Image alignment
2) Image difference analysis

In the first case we can define the features and their descriptions in both images using [SIFT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) / SURF based feature discripter. These functionalities are already available with [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) library. Compare the images using their key points. Taking any matching pair of key points in the images find the distance of those key points from any reference point in corresponding images for example left edge of corresponding image and find the difference of these two lengths. This difference is the required length by which one image can be moved in horizontal direction to align with other image and hence images can be aligned using this difference length.

For second case after images have been aligned traverse through all the pixels in both the images in overlapping region compare corresponding pixel values from two images one by one to mark the differences.